# Activity Feed on Xbox One private?

Tags: xbox-one

Recently purchasing a Xbox One, I learned that friends can see your gaming activity on the Feed. I don't want others to see when I started to play a game or when I unlocked a achievement.

What is the process to make my activity private on Xbox One?

I have went to My Profile > Settings > Privacy > set Gaming & App history to "Block", but I can still see my gaming activity appear on the Feed. Is there another method to make my activity disappear from the Feed? Or did my method work and only "I" can see my own activity?

Comment: I believe it's setup that only you see your activity when the setting is toggled. An easy way to test this would be to ask your friends to look at their activity feed and see if you show up.

Comment: You are supposed to see your own gaming history on your feed. There is no other way to see it otherwise. Why don't you get a friend to confirm that they can't see your history? I am pretty sure you setting the option to 'block' is the right approach.

Comment: Appreciate the responses, I will try the given advice and see if my friends truly don't see the Feed. Will comment back shortly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Setting your settings in regard to what others can see to "Block" will prevent them to see the type of content you blocked.

The reason why you are still seeing it is because the functionality to gather all your activities cannot be turned off. Hence your feed is still assembled but not shared (or partially depending on your settings). This will enable you to share past activities should you wish to toggle the settings again.